# How can I display distinct value from a Observablecollection?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone, observablecollection

I have a [Table]`Book` with columns [Column] `Title | Author | Editor | Genre`

I use a Pivot template with the headers Title, Author, Editor, Genre.
Example: I have 3 books like this:

> 1/ Title = "ABC" | Author = "John" | Editor = "Jerry" | Genre = "Novel"
>
> 2/ Title = "EFH" | Author = "John" | Editor = "Harry" | Genre = "Mystery"
>
> 3/ Title = "HJK" | Author = "Tom"  | Editor = "Jerry" | Genre = "Mystery"

**What I want is in each Header just show like this**:

in Title header: `ABC  |  EFH  |  HJK`

in Author header just shows: `John  |  Tom`

in Editor header just shows: `Jerry  |  Harry`

in Genre header just shows: `Novel  |  Mystery`

Code:

```
 <!--Book-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Book">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="TitleList" SelectionChanged="TitleList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="466" Margin="0, 0, 0, 12">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0"></Grid>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="40"   Text="{Binding BookTitle}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Button x:Name="Deletebutton" Height="60" Width="60" Click="deleteButton_Click" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}">
                                     <Image Source="/Assets/delete.dark.png" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeVisibility}" Margin="-25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Author-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Author">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="AuthorList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="40"   Text="{Binding Author}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Editor-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Editor">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel3" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="EditorList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="40"   Text="{Binding Editor}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <!--Editor-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Editor">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel4" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="BookImporterList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="40"   Text="{Binding Editor}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <!--Genre-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Genre">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel5" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="GenreList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="40"   Text="{Binding Genre}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

In my MainViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Book> _load = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
public ObservableCollection<Book> Load
{
    get { return _load; }
    set
    {
        _load = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Load");
    }
}
public void LoadData()
{
    var orderedGenre = (from Book b in BookDB.Books select b);
}
```

Comment: no one can help me ? :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of some possible way to get what you want.

In the ViewModel provide one property to store all Books, it is `Load` property in this case. Then declare new property for every Book's property you want to display. Each of them returning collection of distinct values from corresponding Book property. In the setter of `Load` property I raise PropertyChanged event for all properties that return values from `Load` property.

> There are two ways I provide here to get distinct values from ObservableCollection of Book, by using Distinct method, or using GroupBy method. But I prefer the first way just because it shorter/simpler in this case.

```
private ObservableCollection<Book> _load = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
public ObservableCollection<Book> Load
{
    get { return _load; }
    set
    {
        _load = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Load");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Titles");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Authors");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<String> Titles
{
    get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(Load.Select(o => o.Title).Distinct()); }
    //get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(Load.GroupBy(o => o.Title).Select(o => o.Key)); }
}

public ObservableCollection<String> Authors
{
    get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(Load.Select(o => o.Author).Distinct()); }
    //get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(Load.GroupBy(o => o.Title).Select(o => o.Key)); }
}

public void LoadData()
{
    var orderedGenre = (from Book b in BookDB.Books select b);
    Load = new ObservableCollection<Book>(orderedGenre);
}
```

Then in XAML, bind each ListBox's ItemsSource to corresponding property that have been created in ViewModel :

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Book">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="TitleList" SelectionChanged="TitleList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}">
        ....

        ....
<controls:PivotItem Header="Author">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="AuthorList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}">
        ....

        ....
```